# How to print/display MathML expressions?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, mathml

Currently I'm trying to use a textField with `markup="html"` but it's not working.

**Example**

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
<reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="100" y="0" width="450" height="25" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="1aeaa5e9-4136-4239-a301-2733598340d9">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
</reportElement>
<textElement verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html">
    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single" leftIndent="5" rightIndent="3"/>
</textElement>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{question}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

**$F{question} contain:**

```
"<p id="id"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mi>A</mi><mo>+</mo><mo>&#160;</mo><mi>B</mi><mo>&#160;</mo><mo>&#160;</mo><msqrt><mi>c</mi><mfenced><mrow><mi>d</mi><mfenced open="[" close="]"><mi>r</mi></mfenced></mrow></mfenced></msqrt><mo>&#160;</mo><mi>&#948;</mi><mo>&#160;</mo><mo>&#8734;</mo><mi mathvariant="normal">&#960;</mi><mo>&#160;</mo></math></p>"
```

**Expected Result  :**

[image: Expected Result]

**Result which I get :**

[image: Result which I get]

Answer (score 1):

The textField does **not** support MathML, it only support very basic html nor can you use the html component since the JEditorPane on which it's built neither does support MathML

You will need an external library as for example [jeuclid](http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/), once that you have this library in classpath you can render the xml to a `BufferedImage` using [`Converter.render`](http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sourceforge/jeuclid/converter/Converter.html#render(org.w3c.dom.Node,%20net.sourceforge.jeuclid.LayoutContext)) and then display it in jasper report.

This can be done without a java helper class as in this example, hence writting all the code directly in the jrxml on 1 line (using the builder pattern below), but for clarity of example I'm will use external helper class.

## Example

### java

```
public class MathML {
     public static BufferedImage getImage(String xml, float size) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {          
        // Load the string to a node
        Element node =  DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
                .getDocumentElement();              
        //Generate the layout parameter
        MutableLayoutContext params = new LayoutContextImpl(
                LayoutContextImpl.getDefaultLayoutContext());
        params.setParameter(Parameter.MATHSIZE, size);      
        //Render the xml to a BufferedImage
        return Converter.getInstance().render(node, params);
    }
}
```

### jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_12" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="8deaea2e-3739-4c4e-b2b5-8c58773ab1a0">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" uuid="9ee17167-a91e-4725-b36e-a4bba5e24acb">
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[it.jdd.MathML.getImage("<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'><mi>A</mi><mo>+</mo><mo>&#160;</mo><mi>B</mi><mo>&#160;</mo><mo>&#160;</mo><msqrt><mi>c</mi><mfenced><mrow><mi>d</mi><mfenced open='[' close=']'><mi>r</mi></mfenced></mrow></mfenced></msqrt><mo>&#160;</mo><mi>&#948;</mi><mo>&#160;</mo><mo>&#8734;</mo><mi mathvariant='normal'>&#960;</mi><mo>&#160;</mo></math>",70f)]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

### Output (export to pdf)

[image: Export to pdf]